What're the differences between redirecting output to file either redirect output to temporary file and move temporary file to the end file?
I've found two ways of recording command output to the file:
cmd > /tmp/output

cmd > /tmp/tmp_output && mv -f /tmp/tmp_output /tmp/output

the second way is messy up, what can be the cause of using it?

In your second command
cmd > /tmp/tmp_output && mv -f /tmp/tmp_output /tmp/output

the mv-command is not necessarily executed, it will only be executed, if the cmd-command exited with an exit status of zero.
